# InteractivePopGestureRecognizer not animating correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have rather complicated structure of my `UIViewController`s, so `interactivePopGesturerecognizer` behaves strange.

First, my VC hierarchy is as follows: I have a `UINavigationController` which is in `AppDelegate`'s `rootViewController` VC. Then I push a VC which servers as a placeholder for 5 VCs on same level, i.e. those VCs are siblings which I use as VCs in infinite horizontal scroll system. I add their `view`s to pushed VC. Now, each of those 5 VCs have `UITableView` and after pressing rows, those tables push details VC on stack. Details VCs are being animated just fine when being pushed to stack. Even when I hit back button on details VC, I see parent `UITableView` animating in the background. The problem arises when I try to swipe the details VC to pop it off stack. Then I get this, there is no `UITableView` in the background that animates.[image: There's no UITableView!]
So far, I've done this:
- in my `AppDelegate.m` I enabled interactive pop gesture `navigation.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;`

- in my details VC I set delegate `self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;`

When the animation finishes, i.e. details VC goes right off the screen, my parent VC with table magically shows up. This doesn't happen if I press button, in that case, that `UITableView` animates from left and stays in position.

I presume that since I'm having situation with horizontal scroll `UINavigationController` loses it's position after I scrolled to another `UITableView` so parent table is someplace else. But how come when I press the back button, I can see that table animating from left?

I also tried to explicitly add `UITableView` of current VC that is on screen to navigation stack by pushing it, but the problem arose when I tried to pop it of stack and show it again, it stayed invisible.

I don't want to have multiple `UINavigationController`s because when I swipe them inside `UIScrollView`, I want my bar to be fixed in position.

So, main question is: how to have the same visual behaviour with `interactivePopGestureRecoginzer` as I get with back button for free (animated parent `UITableView`), considering the fact that I have 5 sibling VCs that are not part of navigation stack, but merely their views added to parent VC which is on navigation stack?

Thanks!

Comment: you should not change the delegate of interactivePopGestureRecognizer.

Comment: @Andy What do you mean by that? Are you suggesting I put it in AppDelegate? I tried to put it there, but the problem was the same

Comment: No I *LITERALLY* suggested that you should not change the delegate of interactivePopGestureRecognizer. You don't even have to enable it explicitly because it is enabled by default.

Comment: OK, I'll try that now

Comment: If I don't set it, swipe isn't working

Comment: You have to establish a relationship between interactivePopGestureRecognizer and your other gesture recognizers and fail one or another depending on the expected mechanics. Also, You may want to look towards UIPageViewController. When you change the delegate of interactivePopGestureRecognizer, you effectively break it, because navigation controller cannot receive signals from it anymore..

Comment: I'll try disabling multiple gestures, and look into UIPageViewController. Thanks for advices. I'll post here my findings.